# Tcl: Get stdout from exec bash

Tags: tcl

Within tclsh I can run the following and get the expected output:

```
% exec bash -c "ulimit -v"
50331648
```

However within a Tcl script nothing is returned. No error, no output, nothing. There's clearly some gotcha with exec'ing 'bash -c' that I can't work out.

Alternatively, is there a native way in Tcl that I can get the system's memory limit to avoid having to do it this way in the first place?

Comment: That's weird. I've not been able to find the conditions under which a simple `ulimit -v` prints nothing. What you are doing _should work…_

Comment: Even looking at (a mirror of) [the relevant bash source](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/ulimit.def) I _still_ don't see why that might be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In an *interactive* tclsh session, the REPL helpfully prints the output of commands/expressions. That's not the case in a non-interactive program.

`exec` **returns** the output of the command: you just need to capture it with the usual command substitution:

```
set output [exec bash -c "ulimit -v"]
puts $output
```

Comment: Thanks - I see the distinction now. It turns out my problem is the Tcl environment, I'm not running a normal Tcl script, this is something within an [environment module](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html) script. It seems that it sucks away the output from 'bash -c' in a way that normal Tcl scripts don't.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you wrote should work; I can't identify why bash would silently fail to run `ulimit -v`. Even if the script was running in an environment where that was privileged information (why!?) one would still expect to get an error message of some form. That's a very weird problem!

---

Tcl's base command set doesn't expose any access to memory limits, whether for reading or writing. The simplest workaround that doesn't call an external program is [the tclbsd package](https://github.com/flightaware/tclbsd) (apparently it mostly works on most other Unixes as well), which exposes a command that should help:

```
package require BSD

set limit [bsd::rlimit get soft virtual]
```

Comment: Useful, thanks. Unfortunately I can't add any additional packages in this case.